# Mysql check multiple rows of same id

Tags: mysql

I'll start off with my table:

```
id    |   name    |   label_id  | package_id
 1        Fred         23742        1056
 2        Fred         23742        1351
 3        Jack         43743        1057
 4        Jack         43743        1352
 5        Bob          13523        1056
 6        Anna         58232        1056
 7        Anna         58232        1057
```

So each person has their own label id but shared package_ids. I just want the all the people that could have package ids of (1056 OR 1057) AND (1351 OR 1352 OR 1353)

```
 1        Fred         23742        1056
 2        Fred         23742        1351

 3        Jack         43743        1057
 4        Jack         43743        1352

 6        Anna         58232        1056
 7        Anna         58232        1353
```

but exclude people that have a single row like bob

```
 5        Bob          13523        1056
```

I'll try to elaborate more if needed because its difficult for me to explain.

Comment: In your table...the 2nd pack id for Anna is 1057 but 1353 in your results...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this. This will select all rows where the package_id is in the numbers you listed, and excludes people that only have one row in the table.

```
select * from <table-name> 
where package_id in (1056, 1057, 1351, 1352, 1343)
and name in (
    select name from <table-name>
    group by name
    having count(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: This will not address the part saying "I just want the all the people that could have package ids of (1056 OR 1057) AND (1351 OR 1352 OR 1353)".

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4aed9/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(4), `label_id` int, `package_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO mytable
    (`id`, `name`, `label_id`, `package_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Fred', 23742, 1056),
    (2, 'Fred', 23742, 1351),
    (3, 'Jack', 43743, 1057),
    (4, 'Jack', 43743, 1352),
    (5, 'Bob', 13523, 1056),
    (6, 'Anna', 58232, 1056),
    (7, 'Anna', 58232, 1353)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from mytable
where name in (
    select name
    from (
        select distinct name 
        from mytable
        where package_id in (1056, 1057)
        union all
        select distinct name 
        from mytable
        where package_id in (1351, 1352, 1353)
   ) as result
   group by name
   having count(*) > 1)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4aed9/5/0)**:

```
| id | name | label_id | package_id |
|----|------|----------|------------|
|  1 | Fred |    23742 |       1056 |
|  2 | Fred |    23742 |       1351 |
|  3 | Jack |    43743 |       1057 |
|  4 | Jack |    43743 |       1352 |
|  6 | Anna |    58232 |       1056 |
|  7 | Anna |    58232 |       1353 |
```